# Refactoring 3 cyclic classes

Tags: c++

I have made a big edit in attempt to clarify what help I am asking for and to try to make the question appropriate for Stack Overflow.

The problem in general:  I have an existing library class which allows me to query a server for information.  That library class is widely used by a large amount of legacy software, so I am somewhat limited in the changes I can make to it.  Likewise, reimplementing it in a better fashion might not be time well spent.

The problem in specific:  I've create a simplified "toy" model of my approach below with 3 classes.  The real thing is more complex, as there are polymorphic variations, more functionality, error handling, etc.

In "toy" model code included below, *Gateway* is the existing library class.  I've tried to show how I would like to use it, with a result set and a way to access each member of the set.  The idea is similar to how a well-implemented database API might look, with a statement, result and row -- except in my case, what would be the statement class is hobbled by a poor design which includes part of the result functionality.

The toy example below will not compile as-is because of the following cyclical dependecy.  The *Gateway* class includes the *ResultSet* class and depends upon it, as it returns a *ResultSet* object.  The *ResultSet* class depends on the *Member* class, as it uses it to convert the data returned from the server into primitives (e.g. string).  But the *Member* class refers back to the *Gateway* class to access that data, and so there is a cycle.

I want to find a solution which will provide the *ResultSet* and *Member* functionality.

For a simpler 2 class problem, I know a solution.  It is to create a superclass that one class derives from (is-a), and which the other class is composed of (has-a), such that both original classes depend on the third, and all is right with the world.  :-)

For my 3 class problem, for some reason I have been unable to wrap my head around how to refactor it to make it work.

```
// Gateway.h
#include "ResultSet.h"
class Gateway {
    ResultSet exec(string params);
};
// Gateway.cpp
ResultSet Gateway::exec(string p) { ... }

// ResultSet.h
#include "Member.h"
class ResultSet {
    ResultSet();    // ctor
    int     index;
    bool    next();
    string  getCurrent(Member member);
};
// ResultSet.cpp
ResultSet::ResultSet() { index = 0; }
bool    ResultSet::next() { ++index < length; }
string  ResultSet::getCurrent(Member member) { member.fetch(index) }

// Member.h
#include "Gateway.h"
class Member {
    Gateway gateway;
    string  fetch(int i);
};
// Member.cpp
string Member::fetch(int i) { return gateway.sGet(i); }
```

// Example desired usage of the final API.
    main() {
        Gateway     gate;
        ResultSet   set;
        Member      member;

```
    set = gate.exec("...");

    while (set.next()) {
        cout << set.getCurrent(member) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: We're here to help with programming problems, not re-design your system.

Comment: forward declaration? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration#Classes

Comment: I was going to ask, in your opinion, should this be over on programmers.stackexchange.com instead?  I've seen many similar questions here, which is why I placed it here.  But perhaps we're all wrong.

Comment: For the record: This doesn't belong on Programmers.StackExchange either AFAIK.

Comment: @CXJ - Simon's comment is correct.  Implementation issues belong on StackOverflow and not on CR or Progs.

Comment: @GlenH7  Then color me confused.  I'm getting beat up for having it here.  :-(

Comment: @CXJ I have personally upvoted your question here, SO is really the best place for it. But you could describe your problem a bit better, make it more clear what the cycle is in the code, and describe what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I try to respectful of people's time and so try to state my questions as briefly as possible, but obviously I may err in not providing good enough information.  I will take some time and edit my question, so as to try to be more clear and complete.  Thanks.

Comment: @CXJ - The impression I get is that you're looking for a code backed answer for this problem.  That's why I think it fits better here on SO.  The relevant questions on Progs (see [1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/11856/53019), [2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/240904/53019), [3](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/184943/53019)) are much more abstract and won't directly answer what I think is your question.

Comment: @GlenH7 Well, mostly yes.  Yes, in that C++ does not have some features that languages such as Java and PHP have which might help solve the problem, and the solution does need to be in C++.  But if someone can illustrate a solution in any form that I can translate to C++, that would be wonderful as well.  I'm reading the references you provided; thank you very much!

Comment: see [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your issue is to forward declare the overlapping classes in the header files, and then to include their actual .h files from your .cpp implementation files.

For instance, to get around `Gateway`'s dependencies on `ResultSet`,

```
// Gateway.h
class ResultSet;    

class Gateway {
    ResultSet exec(string params);
};
```

This forward declares the class `ResultSet`.

Now in `Gateway.cpp`, we have to provide the actual interface to the compiler. So now we include `ResultSet.h`.

```
// Gateway.cpp
#include "ResultSet.h"

ResultSet Gateway::exec(string p) { ... }
```

We do this for your other cyclic relationships, and you will then have source you can compile and build.

For `ResultSet`, we will forward declare `Member`.

```
// ResultSet.h
class Member;

class ResultSet {
    ResultSet();    // ctor
    int     index;
    bool    next();
    string  getCurrent(Member member);
};
```

And in its implementation file, we will finally include `Member`'s header.

```
// ResultSet.cpp
#include "Member.h"

ResultSet::ResultSet() { index = 0; }
bool    ResultSet::next() { ++index < length; }
string  ResultSet::getCurrent(Member member) { member.fetch(index) }
```

And finally, `Member`...

```
// Member.h
class Gateway;

class Member {
    Gateway gateway;
    string  fetch(int i);
};
```

And of course, `Member.cpp` must then include Gateway's information.

```
// Member.cpp
#include "Gateway.h"
string Member::fetch(int i) { return gateway.sGet(i); }
```

Now there are no cyclic dependencies.

Comment: Using this technique makes my classes compile for me.  Am about to write some test code to make sure they execute as expected.  If so, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.  Thanks.